# Can't delete SPWeb from PowerShell or C# Object Model

Tags: 2010, development, powershell, spweb

I have a very strange situation - two sub webs were created through some code but it errored out part way through the process and now I am left two webs I can't seem to delete. The strange part is that I can see them as an error if I trying to create a new web with the same URL (it complains it already exists) and I get see them in PowerShell using `Get-SPWeb` for the parent site then enumerating the `Webs` property. Using the C# server side object model I can't even see the sites or get a reference to delete them!

Help! How can I delete these rogue sites?

Examples:

### PowerShell

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://server/web
$web.Webs

Url
---
http://server/web/OldMeetingSite
http://server/web/NewMeetingSiteA
http://server/web/NewMeetingSiteB
```

### C# Server Side Object Model

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("web"))
    {
        foreach (SPWeb sub in web.Webs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sub.Url);
        }
    }
}
// output - only one site?!?!?
http://server/web/OldMeetingSite
```

**Note:** I can get some quasi-reference to the webs through PowerShell `$webs.Webs[1]` but the call to `.Delete()` fails with the message `There is no web named "/web/NewMeetingSiteA".`

Answer (score 1):

Per this site:

http://sharenotes.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/deleting-purging-removing-orphaned-sites-or-site-collections/

Give this a try to see if these are orphaned sites:

```
stsadm -o databaserepair -url http://(your site collection's URL) -databasename (site content database)
```

And then if you do find them on the list, run this:

```
stsadm -o databaserepair -url http://(your site collection's URL -databasename (site content database) -deletecorruption
```

If that doesn't work, the page listed has a SQL call that may be able to remove it directly from there. I **strongly** recommend you back up the entire content database before attempting this, as if you accidentally delete a site you didn't want to delete, Microsoft does not support what you're doing and will not be able to do much to help you get it back.

Comment: The first command simply gave back `<OrphanedObjects Count="0" />` - I may need to try one of the more exotic solutions. Thanks though - I didn't know this command existed!

Comment: Yeah, the world of stsadm is a bit obscure nowadays, but there are still a few things that Powershell can't do that it can.